# Gembox find and update cell

Tags: c#, gembox-spreadsheet

I am trying to update an excel file with gembox. I want gembox to search the excel file for a certain string, and update all matches. But the method [FindText()](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/M_GemBox_Spreadsheet_CellRange_FindText.htm) only returns the first occurrence.

I tried the following, but it causes an infinite loop, for some reason the row and column won't update to the next search result.

```
  private void RenameSubCategory(ExcelWorksheet sheet, string subCategoryOld, string subCategoryNew)
  {
     int row, column;
     while (sheet.Cells.FindText(subCategoryOld, false, false, out row, out column)) {
        sheet.Cells[row, column].Value = subCategoryNew;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your `subCategoryNew` text contains `subCategoryOld` text?
In other words, do you perhaps have something like the following:

```
RenameSubCategory(sheet, "Sample", "Sample New");
```

This would result in infinite loop, because you'll always find `"Sample"` in a cell that was set to `"Sample New"` text.
Instead try using one of the [ReplaceText](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/help/html/Overload_GemBox_Spreadsheet_AbstractRange_ReplaceText.htm) methods, like the following:

```
sheet.Cells.ReplaceText("Sample", "Sample New");
```

Or try using the following:

```
private static void RenameSubCategory(ExcelWorksheet sheet, string subCategoryOld, string subCategoryNew)
{
    foreach (ExcelRow row in sheet.Rows)
        foreach (ExcelCell cell in row.AllocatedCells)
            if (cell.ValueType == CellValueType.String &&
                cell.StringValue.Contains(subCategoryOld))
                cell.Value = subCategoryNew;
}
```

I hope this helps.